# Testing NGXS state, Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'State' before initialization

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

hope I find you well. I am trying to unit test a NGXS state in Angular. I was already able to test all other states, but this one keeps returning:

```
An error was thrown in afterAll
  Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'TestState' before initialization
  ReferenceError: Cannot access 'TestState' before initialization
      at Module.SchemaState (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/main.js:17040:60)
      at Module.6616 (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/projects/store/test.selectors.ts:10:14)
```

I created another state with the exact same actions and selectors of this one and it tests ok. I do not know what might be wrong, I followed strictly the NGXS unit testing documentation.

I do not have any test written in the test.state.spec.ts file, just the beforeEach.

```
beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        NgxsModule.forRoot([TestState]),
      ],
      providers: []
    })
```

Would any of you please be able to help find out what might be going on? Thanks in advance.